# How to bind a property to the property of another class (with no UI Control)?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I'm spending hours on Google researching my simple Task.
I'm trying to do bind my variable **TestString** to **TestClass.MeinString**.

If I click on the button "**tb_tbBinding**" TestString and TestClass.MyString should stay the same value.

Relevant code:

```
public partial class Window_Test : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window_Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // Trying to bind TestClass.MeinString to TestString
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(TestClass, BindingTestClass.MeinStringProperty, new Binding("TestClass.MeinString") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
    }



    string _TestString = "Hello World!";
    public string TestString
    {
        get
        {
            return _TestString;
        }
        set
        {
            _TestString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestString");
        }
    }

    BindingTestClass _TestClass = new BindingTestClass("Hallo Lukas!");
    public BindingTestClass TestClass
    {
        get
        {
            return _TestClass;
        }
        set
        {
            _TestClass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestClass");
        }
    }

    private void btn_testclasschanger_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass.MeinString = "Changed String!";
    }

    private void btn_teststringchanger_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestString = "Changed Class!";
    }

}
```

**My Custom Class:**

```
 public class BindingTestClass : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public BindingTestClass(string myString)
        {
            MeinString = myString;
        }

        public string MeinString
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(MeinStringProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MeinStringProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("MeinString");
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MeinStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MeinString", typeof(string), typeof(BindingTestClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        });

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: can u explain what are you tryingto do in detail ?

Comment: I want to stay internal variables the same.
Example:
I have an object of the class Foo which has some properties and I want to bind a certain property of this object to a certain property of my class Bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `Source` property of your binding

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(TestClass, BindingTestClass.MeinStringProperty, 
    new Binding("TestString") { Source=this, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
```

By default bindings use the `.DataContext` as the Source for the binding, however in your case `TestClass` does not have its `.DataContext` set to anything. In fact, I'm not even sure if that's a valid property on `DependencyObject`.

Normally the `.DataContext` is inherited from the object's parent in WPF's visual tree, but since `TestClass` is not part of your visual tree, there's nothing for it to inherit from.

Comment: @MisterPresident No problem, glad that worked for you :)

Comment: MisterPresident accept it as answer, so that community can be benefitted.